# Stop a process running longer than an hour

Tags: powershell

I posted a question a couple ago, I needed a powershell script that would start a service if it was stopped, stop the process if running longer than an hour then start it again, and if running less than an hour do nothing. I was given a great script that really helped, but I'm trying to convert it to a "process". I have the following code (below) but am getting the following error

**Error**
"cmdlet Start-Process at command pipeline position 3
Supply values for the following parameters:
FilePath: "

**Powershell**

```
# for debugging
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*Process:Verbose'] = $true
$str = Get-Process -Name "Chrome"

if ($str.Status -eq 'stopped') {
    $str | Start-Process
} elseif ($str.StartTime -lt (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)) {
    $str | Stop-Process -PassThru | Start-Process
} else {
    'Chrome is running and StartTime is within the past hour!'
}

# other logic goes here
```

Comment: You need to tell Start-Process the location of the executeable to run. You could in theory use the .Path property of the Process objects from Get-Process. The problem is that for an app like Chrome there are many processes. So depending on the extensions that you have loaded you may have one chrome app open with one tab but have 10 processes. In which case what you are trying to do would fire up chrome 10 times. I suspect that this is not what you want.

Comment: Also, one other thing to consider with this is that for something like Chrome, the oldest running process will be the base process. So killing it will close every Chrome tab. Including any tabs where the user might be in the process of filling out forms. What exactly is the goal here. Why do you want to restart processes every hour?

Comment: I have a couple applications that run about every 10 minutes, if they go over an hour something is up and it crashed, if it's not running at 10 minutes something is up. I planned on using task scheduler running on 10 minute increments to run the script

Comment: Ugh...this is a tough thing to do. It depends a lot on the programs and what they do. Would they happen to be ones that you wrote or that were written in house? If so altering their code to restart or kill themselves would be the best plan. Alternatively, What process launches them every 10 minutes? Changing that process to monitor them and kill them would be the next best option.

Comment: Right now I'm working with an EDI application that launches a populate app that pulls the data and moves it out somewhere, that was purchased from a vendor. I'm on the systems side but one of my developers is asking for help because the process will get hung up several times a day when running jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$str` is storing a list of all processes with the name "Chrome", so I imagine you want a single process. You'll need to specify an ID in `Get-Process` or use `$str[0]` to single out a specific process in the list.

When you store a single process in `$str`, if you try to print your `$str.Status`, you'll see that it would output nothing, because Status isn't a property of a process. A process is either running or it doesn't exist. That said, you may want to have your logic instead check if it can find the process and then start the process if it can't, in which case it needs the path to the executable to start the process. More info with examples can be found here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41a7e43c-9bb3-4dc2-8b0c-f6c32962e72c?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

If you're using Powershell ISE, try storing the process in a variable in the terminal, type the variable with a dot afterwards, and Intellisense (if it's on) should give a list of all its available properties.